# Open many PHP header in loop

Tags: php, loops, header, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have to send multiple message in chat telegram with a bot. 
To do this i open an url with will be the text of message... i don't know how is possibile to open many PHP header with a loop.

This is my code:

```
$figli= 3;

for($i=0; $i < $figli; $i++){
 header('Location: https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=@Channel&parse_mode=HTML&text=<b>Forte terremoto in Sud Italia</b>');

};
```

Should send 3 message (with same text) but doesn't works. 
I read that is possible to have only one header but is there another way ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: You can only do a location redirect once. Once it hits your first redirect it will go to a new script and cease execution. Instead of header location redirect, you should probably be using CURL or something to send that message.

Comment: You'll probably need to do this by calling `curl_exec()` in a loop, or maybe something simpler like `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: Sorry can you show me an example ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: Sorry @MichaelBerkowski tell me is if the answer is correct

Comment: @Borja Yes, your answer should work. You could move `curl_init()` before the loop and `curl_close()` after the loop to reuse the same curl resource handle.  You should `urlencode('html string')` the contents of `text=html string`

Comment: sorry @MichaelBerkowski what change if i don't move, like you suggest, curl_close and curl_int ? I need to open same url but different text (see the end part of that url)

Comment: Perhaps create an array of the values you need for `text=` and access it with `$i` from your loop.

Comment: ok i understand but what change if i don't move code like you suggest in previous comment ? The code works fine also like i added in answer but i would understand what change... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Works fine but please tell me if is a good code (because i see `curl_exec()` in other answers and is more complicated than my case)

```
$figli= 3;

for($i=0; $i < $figli; $i++){

 $url=  'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN?chat_id=@CHANNEL&parse_mode=HTML&text=<b>Forte terremoto in Sud Italia</b> !';

 $ch = curl_init();

 // set URL and other appropriate options
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 // grab URL and pass it to the browser
 curl_exec($ch);

 // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
 curl_close($ch);  

 };
```